# How can I make an iframe responsive inside another div?

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I have an iframe that inside a div that's left-aligned in the page (only on large screen, then it drops below and should be as wide as the screen). I want the iframe to shrink to scale when the screen is smaller. Currently, it just cuts the frame off.

Here's what I have

My html:

```
<div id="top_right">

    <iframe id="forecast_embed" type="text/html" height="250" width="100%" frameborder="0" [src]='mylink'> </iframe>

 </div>
```

My css:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
     iframe {
      display:block;
      width:100%;
    }

    #top_right_div {
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      /* height: 260px; */
    }
 } 
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
     iframe {
      display:block;
      width:100%;
    }

    #top_right_div {
      width: 40%;
      display: inline-block;
      /* height: 260px; */
    }
 }
```

Just not sure where to go from here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick we used to do were I work for responsive embed videos, I looked for it and I found it, it was something like below.

You would a have a container and your iframe. Like this:

```
<div class="resp-container">
    <iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" gesture="media"  allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

And then style them like this:

```
.resp-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.resp-iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

Here's a codepen I created to check it https://codepen.io/julia-cipriani-corvalan/pen/Eemery

And the source: https://blog.theodo.fr/2018/01/responsive-iframes-css-trick/

Let me know if helps,